# How to delete session in cakephp 3.0?

Tags: session, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

all code is in one controller

My code goes like this.

```
    public function login()
    {
    $session = $this->request->session();
    $session_event_id = $session->read('Events.event_id');
    $session_division_id = $session->read('Events.division_id');

    if(!$session_event_id || !$session_division_id) {
        $event_table = TableRegistry::get('Events');
        $event = $event_table->find('all', ['fields' => ['id'], 'order' => 'id desc'])->first();
        $session->write('Events.event_id', $event->id);
        $session_event_id = $session->read('Events.event_id');

        $division_table = TableRegistry::get('Divisions');
        $division = $division_table->find('all',['fields' => ['id'], 'conditions' => ['event_id' => $event->id]])->first();
        $session->write('Events.division_id', $division->id);
        $session_division_id = $session->read('Events.division_id');
    }
    }
```

By above code i am able to write and read session values but while logout i want to delete those session data

```
public function logout()
{    
    $session = $this->request->session();
    $this->$session->delete();
    return $this->redirect($this->Auth->logout());
}
```

> Warning (4096): Object of class Cake\Network\Session could not be
>   converted to string [APP/Controller/UsersController.php, line 56]
>
> Notice (8): Object of class Cake\Network\Session to string conversion
>   [APP/Controller/UsersController.php, line 56]
>
> Error: Call to a member function delete() on a non-object File
>   /var/www/html/MEX/src/Controller/UsersController.php

Comment: Please, if you receive errors, even if they are so very basic, always post the _complete_, _exact_ error message, including possible stacktraces!

Comment: i have clearly mentioned error you can check out

Comment: Look at the call of session's `delete()` on logout. You have `$this->$session->delete()` instead of `$session->delete()`

Comment: Thank you. and again these types of errors are coming                Warning (2): Missing argument 1 for Cake\Network\Session::delete(), called in /var/www/html/MEX/src/Controller/UsersController.php on line 56 and defined [CORE/src/Network/Session.php, line 477]

Notice (8): Undefined variable: name [CORE/src/Network/Session.php, line 479]

Warning (2): Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at 

Warning (2): session_regenerate_id() [function.session-regenerate-id]: Cannot regenerate session id - headers already sent [CORE/src/Network/Session.php, line 576]

Comment: Could the error possibly be more clear? `Session::delete()` requires an argument to be passed. No offense, but maybe you should start learning PHP/Programming basics first, before starting to use a fully fledged framework like CakePHP.

Answer (score 7):

You're looking for `$this->request->session()->destroy();`

http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/sessions.html#destroying-the-session

Just a tip - there's not much of a point for storing a variable `$session` for a function that small, where the reuse of `$session` isn't necessary. The only case I'd store `$this->request->session();` in a variable is when I'm accessing the session for multiple read and writes all in the same function.

(As far as the error is concerned, @Eagle is correct in that you're referencing '`$this`' twice by the use of that stored variable.)

Answer (score 4):

Thank You for your supports and help finally i found solution of my problem by myself

```
    $session = $this->request->session();
    $session->delete('Events.event_id');
    $session->delete('Events.division_id');
```

by doing so, i am able to clear session data. Thank you